# Implementing a catch when a status code is 404 with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to catch a 404 error in my modal that I've built but I'm not sure how to go about it. Basically if the API response is 404 then a `div` should appear saying

> sorry, ID cannot be found' along with a close modal button

I have everything else working fine but just not sure how or where to implement this error catch. I would also like to do it without JSX as I haven't written any in this project.

When the API response 404's, the json is as below

```
{"success":false,"reason":{"code":14,"message":"Resource not found."}}
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
getUserProfile() {
  compsApi.get({
      path: `v1/users/profile/${this.props.Id}`,
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ user: response.results });
  })
}

render() {
  const { UID, profile, data } = this.state.user || {};

    return this.state.user
      ? div('.grid', [
        div('.grid__item .one-half', [
            div('.input-block__label-text--bold', 'ID'),
        ]),
        div('.grid__item .one-half', [
            div(`${UID}`),
        ]),
        div('.grid__item .one-half', [
            div('.input-block__label-text--bold', 'Email'),
            div('.input-block__label-text--bold', 'Name'),
            div('.input-block__label-text--bold', 'Date of Birth'),
            div('.input-block__label-text--bold', 'Gender'),
            div('.input-block__label-text--bold', 'Phone Number'),
            div('.input-block__label-text--bold', 'Address'),
        ]),
        div('.grid__item .one-half', [
            div(`${profile.email}`),
            div(`${profile.firstName} ${profile.lastName}`),
            div(`${profile.birthDay}/${profile.birthMonth}/${profile.birthYear}`),
            div(`${profile.gender}`),
            div(`${profile.phones.number}`),
            div(`${data.street}`),
            div(`${data.town}`),
            div(`${data.postcode}`),
        ]),
        div('.modal__spacing-top .align-right', [
            Button({
                onClick: this.props.POP_MODAL,
                buttonText: 'close',
                modifierClassName: ['min']
            })
        ])
      ])
    : div([
        h(TickSpinner, {
            width: 75,
            height: 75,
        })
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your api library 'compsApi' should reject the promise given a 404 and then your promise chain can have a `.catch` on it which would then set the component state to be an error.

Ideally you shouldn't be doing this in a component though and should have a more defined architecture (flux / redux?) that would abstract this all away from your presentational components so they aren't so coupled. But as it stands, rejecting the promise would solve your issue.

```
getUserProfile() {
  compsApi.get({
      path: `v1/users/profile/${this.props.Id}`,
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ user: response.results });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    this.setState({ error: err.message });
  });
}
```

then your compsApi library would simply do a check on the call.

```
 function get(path) {
   //make call
   if (res.success) {
     // do success
     resolve(payload);
   } else {
     reject(reason);
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should vote and accept the answer, it's the best way of giving thanks